# Concatenate string WITHIN a PHP HEREDOC block

Tags: php, concatenation, heredoc

I want to concatenate a string in a long(ish) HEREDOC block.

I am making a very quick and dirty form builder just to use to enter dummy data in the database. I have `$var.Help` in the text block:

```
$out = <<<textOnly
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="$var">$var</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="$var" aria-describedby="$var" placeholder="$var">

    <small id="$var.Help" 

  class="form-text text-muted"> 
  We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
   </div>
textOnly;
```

If I do it with a space I get a space, if I do a dot I get a dot, no space looks for wrong variable and `{}` just causes an error. I know there are plenty of other ways to do this but is there a way to concatenate within a HEREDOC string?

TO CLARRIFY: I want to be able to do:

```
$var = fred;
```

in PHP. Then use that value in the line

```
<small id="$var.Help"
```

to produce the result in HTML:

```
<small id="fredHelp" ...
```

Hope that is clearer.

Errors include:
`$var.Help` which just produces "fred.Help"
`{$var.Help}` produces error
`$varHelp`  produces warning as looking for the variable `$varHelp`!

Comment: Your code fragment generates a string without errors. Please show a complete reproducible example with $var = ? that clarifies your problem or error with the associated error description.

Comment: Thanks for that helped me improve the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{$var}Help` should do the trick. You delimit your var with the `{` and just add the string at the point it needs to be

Comment: Well, everyone can make a mistake, but not everyone can actually make a good question with what you have, what you want and what you tried, so you did the hardest part right: actually asking a good question :D  cheers!